# Can someone overview this?

Tags: php

I have this code, but it doesn't enter anything in the database. What's wrong?

I am in the process of learning how to create registration and login forms, this is what I'm trying to do: 3x4:5,60.9.10:100.1

```
<?php

require_once 'db/connect.php';

$FirstName    = $_POST['FirstName'];
$LastName     = $_POST['LastName'];
$Username     = $_POST['Username'];
$$Password    = $_POST['Password'];
$Email        = $_POST['Email'];
$TokenUtils   = "D2C86A09-2077-48CF-9628-F159BB055EF2";

$CreateUserLink = "INSERT INTO Users (FirstName, LastName, Username, Password, Email, REG_DATE) VALUES     ('$FirstName', '$LastName', '$Username', '$Password', '$Email', NOW())"; ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Ethereal-princess.com // Updates & News!</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sandwich-has-style.css" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
<div id="Container">
<div id="Header">
<h1><a href="#">Ethereal-princess.com</a></h1>
</div>
<div id="Wrapper">
<div id="Content">
<div id="Extra">
    <p><strong>More stuff here.</strong></p>
    <p>sit malesuada lacus pellus parturpiscing. Pellenterdumat maecenatoque cras a magna nibh et quis diam ames et. Laoremvolutpat ac dolor eget eget temper lacus vestibus velit lacus venean. Magnaipsum tellus morbi leo aliquat nulla convallis pellentesque.</p>
    </div>
  <p><strong>Heading #1</strong></p>
  <p>Sapibulumnibh phasellus nulla egestibulum enim pretium elit tincidunt estiquam ultrisque donectetur. Sedcondimentumsan odio hendrerit proin vitae dignis nibh ac justo id congue. Amesintesque vel curabitae volutpat donec alique nasceleifendimentesque montesque rhoncus quis eros. Vestnunc nonummy</p>
  <p>Montegeraliquam sed pede in cursus praesenec vestas rhoncus wisi at wisi. Condisseloborttis enim et ipsum mauristie id felit adipiscipit ac auctortorttitor sempor. Vitantesqueat sempus non sed et mus sit vivamus purus netus hendiment. Pretiuma diam et id tempus dolor por wisi sed volutpat facilisi.</p>
  <p>Wisiet sus adipit phasellentum elit condissim consecteturpiscing sapien vivamus et congue. Utvel tris quismod cursus liberos elit nisse curabitur tur parturpis tellenterdum. Semperligula curabitae tellentesque nulla trices vestas ristibulum id justo auctor facinia. Natisdonec consequat nibh pellus.</p>
  <p>Vestibusodio euisque id elerisus lacus tincidunt sit malesuada lacus pellus parturpiscing. Pellenterdumat maecenatoque cras a magna nibh et quis diam ames et. Laoremvolutpat ac dolor eget eget temper lacus vestibus velit lacus venean. Magnaipsum tellus morbi leo aliquat nulla convallis pellentesque.    </p>
</div>
        </div>
<div id="Navigation">
            <p><strong>Register An Account! Accountability</strong></p>
<ul>
  <form id="Gurkis" method="POST" action="r.php">
        Användarnamn: <input type="text" name="username" required><br>
        Förnamn: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
        Efternamn: <input type="text" name="lastname"><br>
        Lösenord: <input type="password" name="password" required><br>
        Email: <input type="email" name="email" required><br><br>
    
            <input type="checkbox" id="Roots" value="Agree">
            <label for="Roots">Jag Godkänner spelets Regler & Villkor!*</label><br><br>
    
    <!-- Hi there. Phew! This has been quite a journey. I am in the middle of creating a game.       I am very thrilled, but I can't stand the fact that Josefine's mamma is trying to spoil my code. I have, however, removed the evil code from my script. -->
    
   <input type="submit" value="Registrera konto!*">
    </form>
    </ul>
            </div>
 <div id="Footer">
    <p><?php echo "Copyright &copy; Lurking Games AB"; ?></p></table>

    <!-- With 128 AES-encryption* -->
    
    <!-- Jag tar gärna ett glas rött med dig -->
    
    <!-- 3.60 GhZ -->

</div>
</div>

<!-- Signed Eilis -->

</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to create a fully-working registration script.

Comment: There's no code to actually execute the query. And this is vulnerable to sql injection and syntax errors too. You need to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-statement and learn to write your queries securely and successfully.

Comment: You also need to hash your passwords. Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279321/how-to-use-phps-password-hash-to-hash-and-verify-passwords

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that your query is never being executed.

I suggest you to look at the official php documentation to how execute query

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.statements.php

Furthermore your code has serious problem of security for two reasons:

1 - you need to use SQL statement to avoid SQL injection ( give a look at this https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp )

2 - you need to hash the password to verify the integrity of your password, sent during login, against the stored hash so that your actual password never has to be stored